# How to convert form data to django?

Tags: django, django-forms

How to convert form data to django?

I have a html formalary that sends several arrays given. for example:

```
<input name="item[0]nome"/>
<input name="item[0]descriaco"/>
<input name="item[1]nome"/>
<input name="item[1]descriaco"/>
```

This comes from the html form

With this I can pass the data to a view in Django using post and at the same time pass an is_valid. Goodbye then.

When trying to grab the dest object items as array, I came across a problem.

The Django Form returns me the key with the name "item[0]name"

Instead of returning an array with:

```
item[{ 
"nome": value,
"descricao": value},
{ 
"nome": value,
"descricao": value}
]
```

Thank you for attention.

Comment: please add the full form...

Comment: What does it mean **formalary**?

Comment: hank you. I got it sorted out.

Comment: Actually, we did not understand, anyway, yo did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted out.

```
<input name="nome"/>
<input name="nome"/>
<input name="nome"/>...

itens=[]
for item in request.POST.getlist('nome'):
    itens.append({
        'nome': item
    })
```

Thank you Lemayzeur and cezar